# Is it necessary to use serializes in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Is it necessary to use serializers in Django rest? I'm building a project where I came across a scenario where fields in forms add dynamically and then I need to validated and save data into DB. Since fields in forms dynamic, How can we handle this in serializer?
Can we do validations and saving without using serializes?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your use case ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use a serializer. You can do what you would like to achieve in a view. However, serializers help you a lot. If you don't want to use serializer, you can inherit `APIView` at a function-based-view. However, serializer is the first line of defence and valdidates your data. If you avoid validation, an exception can occur at database at the latest. Only a model-serializer or model-form can validate your data and use the model-setting you made. You can validate your data by hand and write a custom validator.

You can bypass a validation in a serializer. What you have to do is overriding of `to_internal()`.

##### serializer

```
def to_internal(self, data):
   return data

def create(self, data):
   # do your saving stuff
   return saved_instance
```

If `request.data` contains fields that are part of your model but not always part of your requested data, you can set

```
class Meta:
   extra_kwargs = {'field_that_is_not_mandatory': {'required': True}}
```

Maybe the [api](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/) can help you as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with Django rest API. So serializer is a good option to convert data into JSON format. If you don't want to use a serializer you can use Django form rather than serializer.